# Program to establish connection then print out data it receives in C (sockets)

Tags: c, sockets

So I'm trying to get used to sockets, as I need to use them to create an intrusion detection program for upcoming coursework.
Something im trying to do at the moment is simply set up a socket file descriptor, bind it to an address, let it listen for any incoming requests, accept them then write them to a file.

The problems i'm having at the moment is, though what I think I'm doing here is correct, I kind of lost my way past the listen() call. I've tried to figure this out and look up the functions but something just isn't clicking at the moment. I've been at this for the past 6 hours and I've hit a dead end.
This code causes a segmentation fault, no doubt caused by the attempt at writing from the connection stream to the output stream.

Two main things I'd really appreciate:
A) Is my current understanding of whats happening (displayed by comments) correct?
B) If anyone could help me with the segmentation fault or suggest a better way to get the data receieved after establishing a connection out to a file that'd be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MYPORT 3490
#define BACKLOG 10
int main(void)
{
  int sockfd = (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    //creates socket file descriptor

  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    // creates sockaddr_in structure

  memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    //zeros out values in servaddr

  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    //sets contraints for servaddr

  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    //binds sockfd socket file descriptor to a sockaddr pointer pointing to
    //memory location of our sockaddr_in servaddr

  listen(sockfd, BACKLOG);
    //listen for incoming connections

  struct sockaddr their_addr;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  int new_fd;
    //initialise sockaddr to store connector/clients socket address
    //create socklen_t (dont know what this is) for the size of their socket
    //new_fd for a new socket

  addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
  new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &their_addr, &addr_size );
    //set the new socket equal to the result of our accept()
    //accept takes the first connection queued on the host socket, pointer 
    //to a sockaddr where the connecting socket will be returned and 
    //the size of the structure to be allocated

  FILE * conn_f = fdopen(new_fd, "w+");
  FILE * output_f = fopen("receiver.txt", "w+");
  //Here I try and set up two streams.
  //One connection stream - conn_f which takes input from our new socket
  //One output stream output_f - which writes to a text file

  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t bytes;

  while ((bytes = getline(&line, &len, conn_f)) != -1) {
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu : %s\n", bytes, line);
    fwrite(line, sizeof(char), bytes, output_f);
  }
  free(line);
  //This was my attempt at reading the input line by line from my connection
  //stream, (conn_f) and writing it to my output stream (output_f)
  //I think this is causing the seg fault ^^

  close(conn_f);
  close(output_f);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you verify that `fdopen()` and `fopen()` don't return an error (actually you don't look for any error in your syscall) ? (by the way, I don't know if you are new in C but your code is very clean). Plus you should stop your loop if `bytes <= 0`

Comment: Yeah, apologies. I normally get round to writing in error checking once the skeleton is working. I'll drop in some checks now and see if I can find anything. But at the moment I've hit a dead end and can't really find anywhere to go.
Also, I'm completely new to C, only started learning it last week, so this is all a bit of a struggle for me at the moment! But thanks :)

Comment: "Yeah, apologies. I normally get round to writing in error checking once the skeleton is working.", bad, how can you know if they are a runtime error ? I bet that `conn_f` or `output_f` is NULL.

Comment: ahaha, good point.  
What I mean is, I avoid writing it hoping I can get my code working, then put all that stuff in at the end. Not good practice at all.
Just wrote in the checks,   
  if(!conn_f)  
  {
 printf("Failed to open network file stream \n");  
 return EXIT_FAILURE;  
  }  
This is getting tripped at the moment, so clearly I must have made a mistake setting up my network file stream

Comment: Try to use `perror("Failed to open network file stream");`, that will give you a clue, by the way I don't know if your can `fdopen()` a socket.

Comment: used perror, prints out "bad file descriptor" so perhaps the issue is coming from not actually setting up my "new_fd" socket file descriptor correctly? Although I really dont see a problem with it

Comment: well, in this case you must continue to rewind and found the error, `new_fd` must be equal to `-1`, so again use `perror()` if `accept()` fail, `bind()` fail etc.

Comment: Okay, added in the rest of my checks. Looks like i'm actually getting my first error during the bind(). perror prints "socket operation on non-socket"

Comment: haha, `int sockfd = (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` => `int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` ? I didn't see that before XD, welcome to C and his `,` operator ! Fell free to answer yourself.

Comment: AHAHA, I deleted my code earlier and typed it all back up because I thought I was doing something wrong, must have just typed it back up incorrectly. oops. Now that's fixed the program doesn't error, however I have a couple teething problems i;d really appreciate some help with :) The program doesn't terminate on its own, perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Also, after running this more than once, I get an error "failed to binf correctly: address already in use" Is this simply not releasing memory that has been allocated?

Comment: If you look at my first comment `while ((bytes = getline(&line, &len, conn_f)) != -1)` => `while ((bytes = getline(&line, &len, conn_f)) > 0)`. "I get an error "failed to binf correctly: address already in use"" => google is your friend or duckduckgo.

Comment: Thank you. Looked it up, and did "ps" in the terminal, I've found, as the program doesnt terminate on its own, when I ctrl-z it stops execution, but the process isn't killed, so it still hangs onto the port. So I have to manually kill the process each time to free up the port to run it again. Strange.
*edit* changed the while loop as you suggested but seems to still get stuck

Comment: Ctrl+z => Ctrl+c

Comment: Okay, fair enough. But shouldn't the program be terminating on its own? I cant tell whether it's getting stuck in the while loop due to a mistake on my behalf, or the queue of connections is always full, so it just keeps looping through. Is there anyway to check this?

Comment: If you change your condition with what I give you, your program should stop when the client disconnect.

Comment: I have changed the operator in the while loop                                        
while ((bytes = getline(&line, &len, conn_f)) > 0)                                               The program still doesnt terminate, and isn't writing out to the text file. Or at least nothing is being written out. I'm extremely new to sockets, so i'm unsure whether I need to manually set up another terminal and somehow echo dummy data into the port, or whether processes should be connecting to it on their own after I set up the port on 3490 *edit* just figured it out, thanks for the help!

Comment: You have code a server, it can't connect to itself, use something like netcat or telnet to connect to your server.

Comment: Yeah i realised that. The one last thing im trying to solve now is, is there a way to get it to not terminate after processing one connection? At the moment I am just echoing dummy data for it to write out, but the process terminates after this, so I'd be unable to perform a second echo. I thought about putting it in a big while loop, but seems like an really bad way to go about it. Would I have to look further into Non-blocking sockets, or perhaps creating child threads to perform the actual transmission of data? Tbh both are out of my skillset atm

Comment: they are several way to do a server, but this section comment starting to look like a forum XD. Please search documentation to create a server in C, (epoll, select or non blocking socket(non blocking mode is not very good in my opinion))